# Show menu only if_page is

Tags: menus

I have created 4 menus (submenus) in wordpress. I need to know how show this menus only if pages ids are "10 and 11 for example. Is possible? I'm desperated after two hours... thanks!

This is my code for one of them:

```
<?php if( has_nav_menu( 'smone-menu', 'responsive' ) ) { ?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                               'container'      => '',
                               'menu_class'     => 'smone-menu',
                               'theme_location' => 'smone-menu'
                           )
        );
        ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the is_page() conditional like this:

```
if( has_nav_menu( 'smone-menu', 'responsive' ) && is_page(array( 10,11 ))) {
```

Comment: I'm assuming these are pages and not post I.D's you provided?